# Could a non-self-contained program be called as an "app"?

Tags: meaning, terminology, computing, technology

Can an add-on for a browser, a plugin for a text processing (like Word) or a content unit for a software (like an [Anki](http://ankisrs.net) deck) be called an app without misunderstanding?

The definition of an app is a self-contained program **or** *piece of software* designed to fulfill a particular purpose; an application, especially as downloaded by a user to a mobile device (Oxford). So according to this definition, as long as the **piece of software** is designed to fulfill a particular purpose, then it is an app, right? Am I considered to be misleading if I mention them as an app? And does writing this kind of "app" make you a programmer, or developer?

I think they are big words, and I don't want to misleading people, but I need to explain to non-geeks know what I am doing.

Comment: Add-ons and plug-ins are not apps.  The app is the thing your add-on or plug-in plugs into.  Many people consider developer and programmer to be interchangeable.  If I were to draw a distinction, a programmer just creates code from someone else’s design while a developer creates the design first then codes it.  Or maybe that’s the difference between a developer/programmer and a *coder*.  It all depends on the names and job functions your particular company uses.

Comment: IT here.  app is different from an add-on. It (add-on) cannot be considered as an app.

Comment: so in general, what is one word for this? Extension? Could a content unit like an Anki deck be called as an extension?

Comment: app is a short term for "application program" and details about application program can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software

Comment: Add-on or extensions, any of the two

Comment: I don't have an idea of how Anki deck works.

Comment: by the way, depending on how a program works, it can be considered as an app, an add-on or even both. it can also be considered as a simple program. Programs, as we know, is a set of instructions that a computer executes.

Comment: @ArchieAzares so an add-on can be considered as an app?

Comment: the program is the one which can be considered as an ad-on or an app. but an ad-on cannot be considered as an app. App is an independent program. it is designed to perform a group of coordinated functions, tasks, or activities for the benefit of the user [wiki]. Add-on on the other hand needs to depend on a specific app to be use. An example would be add-on on your browsers. add-on is installed to be used by other apps

Comment: @ArchieAzares I think that's true, strictly speaking, but language is flexible and evolves, and the meaning of "app" has morphed to include **modules** as well as standalone software.

Answer (score 1):

[image: link to my Chrome browser's add-ons]

I'm a mobile app developer. Here's the default link to my Chrome browser's add-ons. They call them apps too.

This may cause confusion to some users whose only exposure to the word 'app' has been through the use of a mobile device and the 'app stores'.

To avoid confusion just say what type of apps they are - Browser apps, Anki apps, Word apps, whenever you're describing them or what you do.

As for the distinction between programmer/developer, I don't see one and I use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: What's the difference between an app and a program?

Comment: @tchrist about 20 years and some marketing sparkle